# Should I format my hard drive when upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04?

Tags: system-installation

I have a PC with Ubuntu 13.10 installed, and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to do a clean install, that is, I don't want to keep any of my programs. 
In Windows, there's an option that moves all my files to a folder named Windows.old. Is there a similar option with Ubuntu? Or do I need to format my hard drive?

Comment: Assuming you didn't create a separate partition for `/home` when you installed 13.10, you may look into [How to move home directory to a new partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). Once moved, you can install 14.04 in the old `/` partition (the main partition of 13.10) and format it at the time of install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a truly clean install, the HD will be formatted.  I would suggest that you copy your file structure to a portable hard drive, rather then hope to keep a partition on your old hard drive through the process of reinstalling Ubuntu.